# Ehrenfest's Theorem and commutator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator, commutator

I am doing a problem regarding a one-dimensionan harmonic oscillator and I'm stuck at this one thing. If I have two operators defined by $A=a_+^2+a_-^2$ and $B=i(a_+^2-a_-^2)$, where $a_+$ and $a_-$ are the step-up and step-down operators, and I know that $[H,A]=-2i\hbar\omega B$, where $H=\hbar\omega(a_+a_-+1/2)$. I know the $\Psi(x,t)$ and $\langle A\rangle$ as a function of time. Furthermore, I know $\langle H\rangle$ and $\sigma_{H}$. I need to use Ehrenfest's theorem and $[H,A]=-2i\hbar\omega B$ to find $\langle B\rangle$ for all $t$. How do I start?

Comment: Welcome to PSE. My phone will not let me link to PDF, but if you search for EHRENFEST’S THEOREM Nicholas Wheeler, Reed College Physics Department March 1998, this is a good introduction

Comment: Never mind, I found out. $\frac{d\langle A\rangle}{dt}=-\frac{8\omega\sqrt{6}}{5}\sin (2\omega t)=\frac{i}{\hbar}\langle -2i\hbar\omega B\rangle\Rightarrow \langle B\rangle = \frac{-4\sqrt{6}}{5}\sin (2\omega t)$.